# Migration from jboss 4.2 to jboss 7.4 EAP

Tags: java, deployment, migration, jboss7.x, jboss-4.2.x

migrating from jboss 4.2 to jboss 7.4 eap, trying to deploy ear file on jboss 7.4 but here are the errors

{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit."le5.ear"."le5.war".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerContextBootstrap' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/vr-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: SchedulerServiceLocal -- service jboss.naming.context.java.SchedulerServiceLocal
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerContextBootstrap' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/vr-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: SchedulerServiceLocal -- service jboss.naming.context.java.SchedulerServiceLocal
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerContextBootstrap' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/vr-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: SchedulerServiceLocal -- service jboss.naming.context.java.SchedulerServiceLocal
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: SchedulerServiceLocal -- service jboss.naming.context.java.SchedulerServiceLocal
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: SchedulerServiceLocal -- service jboss.naming.context.java.SchedulerServiceLocal"}}

this was deployed successfully on `Jboss 4.2` GA but not on `7.4`

Added datasource, JAAS authentication in standalone.xml,
tried on both standalone and standalone-full but issue is same on both.

struts framework
Jboss 7.4.

Please let me know if you have any solution.